# Express/Heroku: Loading CSS/JS in One Folder but Not Another. Working Locally/Foreman but not Online

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, express

Can't think of any reason this is happening and couldn't find elsewhere.  Foreman and Local host are loading my bootstrap css/js just fine, but when I push to Heroku they aren't being read/styled.

```
doctype html
  html
    head
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content

    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

They are all local in `public` folder and file structure is correct.  For example:

Loads: https://loc8r1989.herokuapp.com/stylesheets/style.css

Doesn't load: https://loc8r1989.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css

In case it matters this is the `package.json`:

```
{
"name": "Loc8R",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node bin/www"
},
"engines": {
"node": "0.10.33",
"npm": "1.4.28"
}, 
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.10.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
"debug": "~2.1.1",
"express": "~4.11.1",
"jade": "~1.9.1",
"morgan": "~1.5.1",
"serve-favicon": "~2.2.0"
}
}
```

Again this is working locally and on Foreman but not online.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the same CSS/JS in different folders, one failing to load (i.e. apples-apples) or different CSS/JS in different folders (i.e. apples-oranges)?  I see an error `404 Not Found:   app.use.res.render.message (/app/app.js:30:15)` so suspect its not finding a resource.  The Amelia Bootstrap CSS reference glyphicons, etc. in neighboring directories not part of the download (e.g. `src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');`)  Maybe they're on local host, but  by git in `.gitignore` and thus not pushed to Heroku?

Comment: Tried the link and it's a 2 year old solution that didn't work for me.  I added `process.env.PWD = process.cwd()` and a line to `app.use(express.static(path.join(process.env.PWD, 'public')));`  I checked for gitignore files and don't have any and the files are also hosted on the github repo.